# Ajax Session Time Out FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory not working with shiro

Tags: java, jsf-2, session-timeout, shiro, omnifaces

Details of the code that i have added for using Ajax Session time out, as described by [BaluC](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html)

**Faces-Config.xml**

```
<factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/expired.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
```

**application-config.xml**

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <!-- override these for application-specific URLs if you like: -->
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/dashboard" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/login" />
    <property name="filters">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="authc">
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter" />
            </entry>

        </util:map>

    </property>

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
        [main]
           user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

        [users]
            admin = password

        [urls]
           /login.xhtml = user
            /css/**=anon
            /images/**=anon
            /emailimages/**=anon

            /login=anon
            /test=anon

            /sso=anon
            /ssologin=anon
            /**=authc


        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="facesFilter" class="com.xxx.temp.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter"></bean>
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <!-- <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/> -->
    <property name="realms">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jdbcRealm" />
            <ref bean="googleRealm" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="realms" ref="jdbcRealm googleRealm" /> -->
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
    <!-- <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/> -->

</bean>





<!-- <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager"> 
    <property name="cacheManagerConfigFile" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/> </bean> -->

<bean id="passwordService"
    class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService">
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehCacheManager" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="sessionManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO"/> </bean> -->

<bean id="ehCacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />

<!-- <bean id="sessionDAO" class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO"/> -->





<bean id="jdbcRealm" class="com.xxx.domain.web.permissions.MyWebRealm">
</bean>

<bean id="googleRealm" class="com.xxx.domain.web.permissions.GoogleRealm">
    <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> -->
    <property name="credentialsMatcher"> <bean class="com.fetchinglife.domain.web.permissions.GoogleCredentialsMatcher"/> </property>
</bean>

<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean
    class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor" />
```

Added class file `FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter`
** code copied from BaluC blog  **

**Jar files added**

```
omniface-1.7.jar
```

**Added this in .xhtml file**

```
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
```

*came up with a warning*

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: 
 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

**Current status:**

No response found, page wont redirect on Session timeout ajax call.

Comment: It looks like that you configured the `FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter` as a Spring managed bean instead of as a Shiro filter. Why? That was absolutely not described as such in the JSF2-Shiro tutorial which you found.

Comment: @BalusC I am not that good with shiro and spring, i don't exactly know how this works. I have just followed the instructions, In my application there is no     shiro.ini file, so when i searched in the web it showed me this example which i have implemented. Can you help me in fixing this.  :)

Comment: So you don't even have Shiro up and running in first place? I'd work on that first using plain vanilla HTML  pages until it works and then you can start concentrating on fixing problems with JSF ajax stuff. Eat the elephant with one bite at a time.

Comment: @BalusC Yes shiro is working fine , i was just fixing the ajax timeout issue. I am using spring-jsf  with shiro, i will update the application config.xml with complete details

Comment: Okay. Well, sorry Spring is beyond me. Good luck on that.

Comment: @BalusC Oops, I have spend the last 5 day trying to fixing this, still haven't seen the light. Any ways i have updated the application-config.xml. Please take a look when you are free. I am stuck in the middle of a sea. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I checked the updated `application-config.xml` and the value of `filterChainDefinitions` represents exactly the contents of a `shiro.ini` file. I'm not sure why and how Spring does it like that, but it would logically make sense to treat it like a real `shiro.ini`. I'd just configure the Shiro filter over there like as instructed for a real `shiro.ini` file.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for looking into it. I will try to implement it with shiro.ini. Let me check whether it make any difference. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using this configuration.

**faces-config.xml**

```
<factory>
<exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Make Shiro JSF ajax aware by adding [FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#MakeShiroJSFAjaxAware)

Added `<bean class="com.xxx.custom.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter" />` to `util:map`

**application-config.xml**

```
<util:map>
<entry key="authc">
<bean
class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter" />
<bean class="com.xxx.custom.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter" />
</entry>
</util:map>
```

**web.xml**

Added error redirect page to the `web.xml`.

```
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

> **Mistake in my part.**
>
> There happens to be a `SessionTimeoutFilter` which was used for
>   redirecting non Ajax Timeout events, Due to some personal reasons,
>   they wont works peacefully together and i still don't know what 
>   made the angry, when staying together. Any help on that is greatly appreciated.
>
> **This is the code i removed**
>
> ```
> <filter>
> <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
> <filter-class>com.xxx.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
> <init-param>
> <param-name>SessionTimeoutRedirect</param-name>
> <param-value>/login</param-value>
> </init-param>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
> <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
> <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```