# JSF AJAX and normal redirect to login and back to previous page

Tags: session, jsf-2

**Current status :**

If any session time out occurs, `redirectToLogin` function  in `FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter` will be executed. From there I can redirect to any page I need. I get the URI in all cases.
It's all working fine and big thanks to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc).  :)

**Now the second part which makes the issue**

> Redirect to login and come back to the previous page.
>
> **For Eg :**
>
> ***Page 5***----> ***Login***------> ***Page 5***

I have appended the redirect URI to the login URI and retrieved the values from the bean.

But the problem is that I have 2 pages before the user login. A login mode selection page (ie; google authentication or default login) and the page that reads the username and password.

**How can I pass the redirect `URI` through both the pages.?**

This is the code I have used to redirect at Ajax time out and in normal session time out.

**Class `FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter`**

```
   if ("partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
                res.setContentType("text/xml");
                res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                res.getWriter().printf(FACES_REDIRECT_XML, request.getContextPath() + getLoginUrl()+"?redirectUrlPattern="+request.getRequestURI());
            }
            else {
                if (request.getRequestedSessionId()!=null && (!SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated() || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid())) {
                    response.sendRedirect(getLoginUrl()+"?redirectUrlPattern="+request.getRequestURI());
                    return; 
                }
                super.redirectToLogin(req, res);
            }
```

Method used is `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory` in `Omniface`.

I have used a method of appending the values to the URI, but it fails to identify whether the session is expired or a session not created (when a user logs in at first).

**Problem Code**

```
if (request.getRequestedSessionId()!=null && (!SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated() || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()))
```

I am looking for a way to identify the expired session from new session created before login.

Wish to implement this in a Better Way.

A method which will not append present URI with the redirect URL is most welcomed.

Comment: Maybe you have typo in BaluC, it should be BalusC. You can create 1 more filter which will prevent session expired situation.

Comment: preventing session expired is not a good way i guess..!! In my problem the handling session time out is done. The redirection is the problem part now.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded out a solution but still i don't find it as the best solution. Any other answer for doing it is greatly appreciated.

**Step 1**

Configure the application to detect Ajax Timeout and normal timeout. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403095/1844148) is how i did it..!!

**Step 2**

Finding the URI when session timeout occurs, using this.

`FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter` will grab the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` for you.
form that you can convert that to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` using this

```
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response= (HttpServletResponse) res;
```

The `request.getRequestURI()` will get you the redirect URI

```
    String redirectURI=request.getRequestURI();
```

Now you want to save this to some storage so that you can use it in any place you want. The only way i found is to append it with URL using this.

```
res.getWriter().printf(FACES_REDIRECT_XML, request.getContextPath() + "/sessionexpired"+"?redirectUrlPattern="+request.getRequestURI());
```

or

```
response.sendRedirect("/sessionexpired"+"?redirectUrlPattern="+request.getRequestURI());
```

Now on the page load of my sessionExpiry page bean, i used this to grab the value passed through the URL

```
redirectUrl=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("redirectUrlPattern");
```

Now using JavaScript i set that value of `redirectUrl` to [localStorage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22401800/1844148) is how you can save values to local storage.

This is my sessionexpiry.xhtml page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setRedirectURIToLocalStorage(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
      {
        localStorage.redirectURI=document.getElementById("redirectUrl").value;
        window.location.href="/login";
      }
}
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body id="body" onload="setRedirectURIToLocalStorage()">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:form prependId="false" >  
<h:inputHidden id="redirectUrl" value="#{sessionExpBean.redirectUrl}" />
<h:outputText value="Session Expired... Redirecting...!!"></h:outputText>
</h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

> The page will call `setRedirectURIToLocalStorage()` function `onLoad`
>   and then it set the values to the [localStorage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html). Thus the redirect
>   value is available all across the browser. You can use that in any
>   page you need.!!  All you need to do is to check in this variable
>   `localStorage.redirectURI`